# Rails: From local MySQL to Heroku

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

I am working on a localhost app which is backed by a MySQL database.  However I would like to deploy to Heroku which I have read is bacekd by PostGreSQL.

What is the best way of doing so? I have thought of doing this in the Gemfile:

```
group :development do
 gem 'mysql2'
end

group :test do
 gem 'pg'
end
```

But, how would I configure the **database.yml**? 
Is this the correct approach?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This page has an example configuration:

[Tutorial: Rails 3.2 with Ruby 1.9.3 on Heroku · RailsApps](http://railsapps.github.com/rails-heroku-tutorial.html)

That tutorial assumes you have SQLite locally. If you want MySQL, just use in your Gemfile

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'mysql2'
end
group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end
```

> But, how would I configure the database.yml

You do not have to do any special setup; Heroku will generate it for you once you push.

Note ([from Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails3)):

> We highly recommend using PostgreSQL during development. Maintaining parity between your development and deployment environments prevents subtle bugs from being introduced because of differences between your environments.

Local gems note (from [the tutorial](http://railsapps.github.com/rails-heroku-tutorial.html)):

> Run `bundle install --without production` to update your gems. The flag `--without production` allows you to skip local installation of the pg gem; otherwise, you will have to install PostgreSQL locally (the pg gem won’t install if PostgreSQL is not installed).